# Android Custom URL Scheme - Source application

Tags: android, multitasking, url-scheme

Is there a way to get the source application in Android when launched via custom URL Scheme?

Our app is controlled via the browser on the device. you click a certain link, and depending on the arguments, a task is performed. I want to then immediately get back to the browser.

I tried calling `moveTaskToBack(true)` once the task is finished, but for some reason, it takes me back to the home screen, rather than back to the browser. as if this method was called from the browser's activity.

So, if I can get the source application, I could launch it via intent.

is it possible? other suggestions on doing this are also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You could just call `finish()` ?

Comment: Well, it works a lot better with `finish()`, however, if the app is completely closed, clicking a button launches the activity and not moving back. if it's in the background, then it works great